# How do i centre a fieldset horizontally in a JQM website

Tags: jquery-mobile

I did a very basic page
I'm trying to centre fieldset horizontally. I tried to wrap it inside `<centre>` but it didn't work.
What should I do?

Here is my code

```html
<div data-role="content">   
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                //Its left align, how do i centre align
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-c" value="on" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="radio-choice-c">Recent</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-d" value="off" />
                        <label for="radio-choice-d">Upcoming</label>
                </fieldset>
    </div>        
<ul data-role="listview">   
       //my list                       
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick I've found that works for me is to wrap the fieldset in another div and put the following CSS on that div either inline or in your CSS file.

```
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
```

So you'd end up with something like

```
<div class='fieldset-center-wrapper'>
  <fieldset>
    your stuff here
  </fieldset>
</div>
```